# Make a probability mass function and plot it?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

If, for example, I am given the probability mass function of a discrete random variable $X$, $P(X=0)=0.5$, $P(X=1)=0.3$ and $P(X=2)=0.2$, then how do I make a probability mass function out of it so that I can apply `DiscretePlot` to it?

Answer (score 6):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{{1/2, x == 0}, {3/10, x == 1}, {2/10, x == 2}}], {x, 0, 2, 1}];

Simplify@PDF[dist, x] // TeXForm
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{5} & x=2 \\
>  \frac{3}{10} & x=1 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} & x=0
> \end{cases}$$

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A compact way is to use `EmpiricalDistribution[]`:

```
emp = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.5, 0.3, 0.2} -> {0, 1, 2}];
```

Verify its properties:

```
Table[Probability[z == k, z \[Distributed] emp], {k, 0, 2}]
   {0.5, 0.3, 0.2}
```

Plot:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[emp, k], {k, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> None, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: plot of PMF]

Comment: Oh good, I can also use mathematica's "Probability" function on it. Thanks